# Xcode static file headers not being copied

Tags: xcode8, static-libraries, header-files

I've been refactoring an existing app so that some of the objective-c can be re-used in a new app by creating a static library. I've never done this before so I followed the raywenderlich tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial)

It all works OK except I don't get any header files in the products folder (as per the tutorial) This means that when I link the projects the compiler complains that the header files aren't found. My built project and the output folder are shown in the screen shot below:

[image: static library Xcode build and folder]

I'm sure its something simple but I can't work out what I'm missing - any ideas would be appreciated